# SQL Server database restore from backup changes all dates with datetime2 type return with values to future dates

Tags: sql-server, restore, datetime2

I'm trying to restore a SQL Server database from a .bak file. 
The process completes without any issues, but the dates with datatype datetime2 are presented with totally different values (change to future dates, e.g. I see dates 1/1/4014). 
The source backed-up database collation is Cyrillic_General_CI_AS.
The login user has been set to have English-us and Russian language but the same issue persists in both cases.
Other types of data, e.g. float numbers, are ok (and readable), only dates are affected.

What exactly is the issue here and can it be resolved?
Is there a specific step we missed and we need to configure?

Comment: What are the SQL version of the backup and destination server ? Also, can you run "select @@language" on both instance

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new database with a single table?  This should not be happening.

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher 
Source Version: 12.0.5540.0, Language: Russian
Destination Version: 140.2024.2, Language Russian

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce... There is no trigger that could alter the data after the restore ? can you do as suggested by David and create a new DB with a simple table containing datetime2 that you can backup and restore to see if you have the same behavior ?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft we created a new DB with a table containing a field with type datetime2 and then produced a backup and restored the DB from the backup file the date seems to come just fine.

Comment: The current sql server management studio version utilized is 14.0.2027.2 while the bak database file was produced with Software version build 12.0.5540.0 are there any hot fixes that we need to apply in order to allow backward compatibility? can someone suggest where to find these?

Comment: Guys is anyone able to help on this?